# Acitvity Indicator doesnt show up in ios 5 but it is visible in ios 4

Tags: titanium

I am using Titanium studio for development, acitvity indicator doesnt show up in ios 5 but it is visible in ios 4...please help

Code:-

```
var activityIndicator = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator
({ 
    style:Ti.UI.iPhone.ActivityIndicatorStyle.BIG, 
    top:45, 
    left:128, 
    font:{ fontSize:14, fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue', fontWeight:'bold'},       
    message:'loading..' 
 }); 

 window.add(activityIndicator);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow.... please show some code that you are using ..

Comment: here is the code .....                                                                 var activityIndicator = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator({
   
   style:Ti.UI.iPhone.ActivityIndicatorStyle.BIG,
    top:45,
    left:128,
    font:{ fontSize:14,
        fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue',
        fontWeight:'bold'},
    message:'loading..'
  });

window.add(activityIndicator);

Answer (score 2):

[First a link to the docs.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.ActivityIndicator) Now some explanation: once you add an activity indicator to a window or view, you also have to show it like this:

```
activityIndicator.show();
```

Then when youre done with it you can hide it like this:

```
activityIndicator.hide();
```

Also note that the BIG style is white and cant be seen on a white background.

As an addendum, this is bad javascript practice :

```
var activityIndicator = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator
({ <----------- Never do this
    .....
});
var activityIndicator = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator({ <-- Thats better
    .....
});
```

This may cause the interpreter to put a semi-colon after the first line, causing problems, and it just looks awful (this is not Obj-C, this is javascript). Refer to [this talk by Kevin Whinnery on "Best Practices for Javascript."](http://player.vimeo.com/video/30035164?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=9a0707&autoplay=1)